# Show a second dropdown based on previous dropdown selection from database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

So I am creating a sample rent a car application using jsp and servlet. The user is shown a drop down list of all the cars make. When the user selects an option from the make, it will then show thee user the specific models based on the make. I am getting all the make and model values from mysql database. I am able to show all the make and model value together but I am not sure how to show the model option based on the make option. After researching online, I found that you have to use javascript but I don't see an example where javascript gets the data from the database.
Here is my code so far:

JSP

## Rent A Car

Please select your type of vehicle

```
        <form name="rentForm" action="RentACar" method="post">
            Car Make: <select name="carMake">
                <%
                    ArrayList<String> getMake = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("make");

                    for(int i = 0; i < getMake.size(); i++)
                    {
                        out.println("<option value=\"" + getMake.get(i) + "\">" + getMake.get(i) + "</option>");
                    }
                %>
            </select>

               Car Model: <select name="carModel">
                <%
                    ArrayList<String> getModel = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("model");

                    for(int i = 0; i < getMake.size(); i++)
                    {
                        out.println("<option value=\"" + getModel.get(i) + "\">" + getModel.get(i) + "</option>");
                    }
                %>
            </select>

        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Servlet

```
public class RentACar extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        ArrayList<String> vehicleMake = RentService.getMake();
        request.setAttribute("make", vehicleMake);
        ArrayList<String> vehicleModel = RentService.getModel(model);
        request.setAttribute("model", vehicleModel);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("rent-car.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String model = request.getParameter("carMake");
    }
}
```

Database Service

```
public class RentService
{
    public static ArrayList<String> getMake()
    {
        ArrayList<String> vehicleList = new ArrayList<>();
        String make = "";

        try
        {
            Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();

            String query = "SELECT make FROM Vehicles";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {            
                make = rs.getString("make");
                vehicleList.add(make);
            }


        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return vehicleList;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getModel(String carMake)
    {
        ArrayList<String> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
        String model = "";

        try
        {
            Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();

            String query = "SELECT model FROM Vehicles WHERE make=? ";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setString(1, carMake);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                model = rs.getString("model");
                modelList.add(model);
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return modelList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686735/populate-one-dropdown-based-on-selection-in-another and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671445/populate-values-into-a-drop-down-list-based-on-another-drop-down-selection-using

Comment: I don't think those are with databases

Comment: You could use something like select2 with ajax to determine what options should be populated in the dropdowns based off of remote data.